# Аналог функции system из C++ для Rust

Tags: c++, linux, rust

Есть ли в *Rust* аналог функции `system` из *C++*? Или что-то подобное, позволяющее посылать команды командному процессору *Linux*.

Comment: по поводу «препроцессора как в cpp»: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485655/using-cpp-macros-with-rusts-ffi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use std::process::Command;

let status = Command::new("ls").status().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
    panic!("failed to execute process: {}", e)
});

println!("process exited with: {}", status);
```

[Документация std::process::Command](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/process/struct.Command.html)

Однако в винде это не сработает. Там можно так:

```
use std::process::Command;
let status = Command::new("cmd.exe").arg("/c").arg("dir").status().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
    panic!("failed to execute process: {}", e)
});
```

Comment: Если не нужна проверка на ошибку - можно так: `Command::new("ls").status();`

Comment: да повесьте вы unwrap() чтоли.